# Service Header Files Missing Error

Tags: ros, cmake, service, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a ROS beginner working on a custom controller for a UUV using Gazebo to simulate the environment and ROS to control everything. I'm using [the uuv_simulator package](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator/wiki), which does a lot of the heavy lifting for me. Currently, when certain conditions are met (i.e. the sonar reads a certain depth) I want the sub to stop moving. Fortunately, there's a service for that, `/rexrov/hold_vehicle`. Here's the results of a rosservice info request on it:

```
$ rosservice info /rexrov/hold_vehicle

Node:
/rexrov/plane_search_standard_controller

URI:
rosrpc://ncopeSub-VirtualBox:35331

Type: uuv_control_msgs/Hold 

Args:
```

I've read all the tutorials I can find, and I'm working heavily with [the services chapter of Jason O'Kane's book](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/agitr-letter-service.pdf), but even when everything's how I think it should be I keep getting this error when I run `catkin_make`:

```
/home/catkin_ws/src/plane_search_standard/plane_detect_anomaly.cpp:4:35:
fatal error: uuv_control_msgs/Hold.h:
No such file or directory 

compilation terminated.

plane_search_standard/CMakeFiles/subscribe_and_publish.dir/build.make:62:
recipe for target
'plane_search_standard/CMakeFiles/subscribe_and_publish.dir/plane_detect_anomaly.cpp.o'
failed make[2]: ***
[plane_search_standard/CMakeFiles/subscribe_and_publish.dir/plane_detect_anomaly.cpp.o]
Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:586:
recipe for target
'plane_search_standard/CMakeFiles/subscribe_and_publish.dir/all'
failed make[1]: ***
[plane_search_standard/CMakeFiles/subscribe_and_publish.dir/all]
Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for
target 'all' failed make: *** [all]
Error 2 Invoking "make -j6 -l6" failed
```

Which seems to say that `catkin_make` doesn't know about the service header file for /rexrov/hold_vehicle. But by everything I've read, it should.

Here're my inclusions in the node file doing the service call:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <uuv_control_msgs/Hold.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
```

Here's the line where I create the service client:

```
ros::ServiceClient stopSubCaller = n.serviceClient<uuv_control_msgs::Hold>("/rexrov/hold_vehicle");
```

Here're the lines where I actually call the service:

```
uuv_control_msgs::Hold::Request req;
uuv_control_msgs::Hold::Response resp;
bool success = stopSubCaller.call(req, resp);
```

And here's my messy CMakeLists.txt file:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(plane_search_standard)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rospy roscpp std_msgs sensor_msgs uuv_control_msgs)



catkin_package()

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/plane_search_standard_controller.py DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY launch
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
PATTERN "*~" EXCLUDE)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})



add_executable(subscribe_and_publish plane_detect_anomaly.cpp)
target_link_libraries(subscribe_and_publish ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(subscribe_and_publish ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I'm going wrong here? I'd really appreciate it - I'm about at my wit's end.

---

More info:

Running `rossrv show uuv_control_msgs/Hold` simply returns:

```
---
bool success
```

If I put `uuv_control_msgs` in the `find_package` command, `catkin_make` generates four errors like this, just with different endings where the _cpp is:

```
CMake Error at /home/ncope/catkin_ws/build/uuv_simulator/uuv_control/uuv_control_msgs/cmake/uuv_control_msgs-genmsg.cmake:321 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target
  "uuv_control_msgs_generate_messages_cpp" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target created
  in source directory "/home/ncope/catkin_ws/src/plane_search_standard".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:307 (include)
  uuv_simulator/uuv_control/uuv_control_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:41 (generate_messages)
```

If I'm reading it right, it's saying genmsg already builds those files? And cutting genmsg of course cuts the generate_messages command entirely.

package.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>plane_search_standard</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The plane_search_standard package</description>

  <maintainer email="ncope@todo.todo">ncope</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <export>

  </export>
</package>
```

I now get an error that looks like this:

```
Could not find the required component 'uuv_control_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "uuv_control_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

    uuv_control_msgsConfig.cmake
    uuv_control_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "uuv_control_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "uuv_control_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "uuv_control_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  plane_search_standard/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271664/service-header-files-missing-error/) by [swordsgnat](https://answers.ros.org/users/32042/swordsgnat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens if you run

```
rossrv show uuv_control_msgs/Hold
```

?

If you're getting a complaint that ROS can't find it or something along those lines then you may need to `source` your `setup.bash`.

Also, it looks like your `CMakeLists.txt` is missing `uuv_control_msgs` from the `find_package` command. Try adding it there and removing it from `generate_messages` and see what happens.

---

**Edit:**

As @gvdhoorn explained in the comments:

> The missing `uuv_control_msgs declaration` (in the `find_package(catkin ..)`) is the problem.
> [...] `uuv_control_msgs` is only a DEPENDENCIES of your `generate_messages(..)` if you are actually building any msgs yourself (ie: in your own pkg). Afaict, you're not. You only depend on someone else's messages. In that case, you need to find that dependency when building, which is what the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS .. uuv_control_msgs ..)` will do.

---

**Edit 2:**

Now, in your `package.xml` you need to add a dependency on `uuv_control_msgs` so add the following lines

```
<build_depend>uuv_control_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>uuv_control_msgs</run_depend>
```

Also, give [the tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) another go as a refresher for you. I still refer to them.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
The missing `uuv_control_msgs` declaration (in the `find_package(catkin ..)` is the problem.

@swordsgnat: `uuv_control_msgs` is only a `DEPENDENCIES` of your `generate_messages(..)` if you are actually building any msgs yourself (ie: in your own pkg). Afaict, you're not. You only depend ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
.. on someone else's messages. In that case, you need to find that dependency when *building*, which is what the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS .. uuv_control_msgs ..)` will do.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-27**:
Thanks for the explanation @gvdhoorn. I should have included that.

**Comment by [swordsgnat](https://answers.ros.org/users/32042/swordsgnat/) on 2017-09-27**:
Hi, thanks for the reply! There wasn't enough space in the comment here so I edited that additional information into the original question at the bottom there.

**Comment by [swordsgnat](https://answers.ros.org/users/32042/swordsgnat/) on 2017-09-27**:
Just read @gvdhoorn's replies (and thank you for the reply): when I add uuv_control_msgs to the find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS..) command, it spits out an error like the one I edited in, claiming that it already has those targets. This persists even when I remove the other packages.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-27**:
@swordsgnat: Did you remove `uuv_control_msgs` from `generate_messages()` after adding it to `find_package()`? That last error is saying that there's already a package with the name `uuv_control_messages` . See https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/477

**Comment by [swordsgnat](https://answers.ros.org/users/32042/swordsgnat/) on 2017-09-27**:
Yes sir - and that error crops up even if I remove the whole `generate_messages()` line.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
@swordsgnat: please update your original question with the contents of both `package.xml` and your edited `CMakeLists.txt`. Also: do an `rm -rf /home/ncope/catkin_ws/build` and `rm -rf /home/ncope/catkin_ws/devel`. Then try again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
Also: remove `genmsg` and `message_generation` from your `find_package(catkin ..)` statement, *unless* you are actually defining your own messages.

**Comment by [swordsgnat](https://answers.ros.org/users/32042/swordsgnat/) on 2017-09-27**:
Reattempted after the rm lines, and I got a new error. I edited it in. I've never touched package.xml  - is that the issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
You should get a different error in that case (something like "uuv_control_msgs should be a build depend of X"), but in any case: check [C++ message or service dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html) to make sure you have everything correct.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-27**:
The error message you quote seems to suggest that Catkin (or really: CMake) cannot find the `uuv_control_msgs`. Make sure you don't have a typo in there somewhere.

I would also suggest to add some entries to your `catkin_package(..)` call, but that can be done later.